# .ser file maximum size in Android

Tags: android, file, size

I have implemented dictionary in Android using **Map Dictionary=new Hashtable();**. I have written the dictionary values into .ser file like the below.

```
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dictionaryfile);
 ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
 oos.writeObject(map);
 oos.close();
```

The dictionaryfile is a .ser file. I want to know the maximum size of the .ser file.

Answer (score 2):

If you are saving on SD card, then the maximum size of a file is the maximum allowed size on the card. If it's FAT32 formatted, then it's 4 GB.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If the file size is 4 GB for example, Is Java Android application is capable of processing the file.? I mean searching, retrieve all the <Key,Value> pair. Is processing time affected by the size of the .ser file.

Comment: Not really, most devices have 16-24 MB maximum heap size, so 4 GB is way above the limit. You should maybe focus on processing the data sequentially, store it in several smaller files or databases.